# How to deal with ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException and StaleObjectStateException when using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, concurrency, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a small RESTful service which uses `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency with `User` domain object defined as `@Entity` and `UsersRepository` extending `CrudRepository`. The service enables clients to reset their forgotten passwords. As the first part, the method that receives email form the client checks whether the user with such email exists and not disabled, if so - creates a temporary reset-token for this user, updates it and sends a special link with the token to the client:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@Validated
public class ResetTokenController {

    private final UsersRepository usersRepo;
    private final JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    public ResetTokenController(UsersRepository usersRepo, JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.usersRepo = usersRepo;
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/auth/reset-token", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Map<String, String> sendMeResetToken(@RequestParam
                                                @NotBlank(message = "Parameter `email` must not be empty")
                                                @Email(message = "Parameter `email` is not valid")
                                                         String email) {
        // step #1: fetch user with given e-mail
        User user = usersRepo.findByEmail(email)
                .filter(User::isEnabled)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                        "User with given e-mail not found or currently disabled"));

        // step #2: create a reset-token for user
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        user.setResetToken(token);
        user.setExpBefore(LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(24));

        // step #3: save user with his new token and send instructions
        usersRepo.save(user);
        MimeMessage message = constructHtmlMessage(token, email);
        mailSender.send(message);
        return Collections.singletonMap("message", "The tokenized link for resetting your password " +
                "was sent to the provided e-mail and will be active for the next 24 hours.");
    }

    // a helper method to construct the mime-message
    private MimeMessage constructHtmlMessage(String token, String email) {

        // here, we build a link based on the token that's been just created
        // and include it in the message along with the instructions details 
        
        return mimeMessage;
    }

}
```

The code above, however, has a potential flaw. Assume, someone (for example, administrator of our service) accidentally intervenes from another thread and deletes a user which is being updated from the database somewhere in the middle between step #1 and step #3. In order to avoid possible inconsistency emerging from such scenario, I first tried to wrap the whole method with `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)`, but discovered soon that making so has no effect since `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` with nested `StaleObjectStateException` will be thrown anyway in such scenario, whether the method is annotated with `@Transactional` or not.

Now, the question is: how to deal with such exception? Personally, I would prefer not to translate it to the client, and the only decision I've reached so far is to put the method's internals into while-loop like this:

```java
public Map<String, String> sendMeResetToken(...) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            // #1: fetch user with given e-mail
            // #2: create a reset-token for user
            // #3: update user and send token
            // leave the loop on successful update
            return Collections.singletonMap("message", "The tokenized link for resetting your password " +
                    "was sent to the provided e-mail and will be active for the next 24 hours.");
        } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException ignore) {
            // continue the loop and make another attempt from the start
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any solution (maybe, more elegant which not uses while-loop) to deal with this situation and, in a more general sense, how such exceptions (I mean, `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` and `StaleObjectStateException`) are usually handled in production?

Comment: Here you have a detailed explanation and solution - https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking

Comment: @AjayKumar, thanks. It's much clearer now.